# sens.slope() vs mblm() in R

Tags: r, time-series, regression, trend

I have been working on Theil Sen's estimator in R and I came across two functions that would produce sens slope, however, they give different values. Anyone know why that is?
First method I used from `sens.slope()` and second method I used from `mblm()`. Both methods used the same data frame

```
tm14D<-data.frame(date=as.Date(date),temperature=temperature,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
tm14D$date<-as.numeric(tm14D$date) #date must be changed to numerical values to avoid difftime error
tm14D.zs<-sens.slope(as.numeric(tm14D$temperature)) #method 1
tm14D.ts_fit<-mblm(temperature~date,data=tm14D)     #method 2
```

And these are the outputs:
**Method 1**
`tm14D.zs$estimates`
   Sen's slope
  *0.0471944*

**Method 2**
`ts_fittm14D$coefficients[2]`
 date
*0.0001055271*

Which one is right and which one is wrong? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

There is also `zyp.sen` from the package `zyp`. `zyp.sen` and `sens.slope` seem to agree.

```
library(trends)
library(zyp)
library(mblm)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,y = 1:100-runif(100,-20,20))

coef(zyp.sen(y~x,df))["x"]
       x 
1.003835 

coef(mblm(y ~ x, df),repeated = FALSE)['x'] 
       x 
1.031631 

sens.slope(ts(df)[,-1])$estimate
Sen's slope 
   1.003835
```

If we review the source of `mblm`, we'll find there is a bug, and that it returns the results of the repeated method regardless of the `repeated =` argument.

```
coef(mblm(y ~ x, df),repeated = TRUE)['x'] 
       x 
1.031631
```

Here is an excerpt of the code of `mblm`:

```
    x = df$x
    y = df$y
#    if (length(term) > 2) {
#        stop("Only linear models are accepted")
#    }
    xx = sort(x)
    yy = y[order(x)]
    n = length(xx)
    slopes = c()
    intercepts = c()
    smedians = c()
    imedians = c()
#    if (repeated) {
#        <snip>
#    }
#    else {
        for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
            for (j in i:n) {
                if (xx[j] != xx[i]) {
                  slopes = c(slopes, (yy[j] - yy[i])/(xx[j] - 
                    xx[i]))
                }
            }
        }
        slope = median(slopes)
        intercepts = yy - slope * xx
        intercept = median(intercepts)
#    }
slope
[1] 1.003835
```

And thus, they all agree.

Comment: In what conditions would you say to use ```mblm()```? should I just stick with sens.slope() and  perhaps ```zyp.sen()```? One reason I wanted to use ```mblm()``` was because I can plot the trend line with the intercept and slope it outputs. I have never used ```zyp.sen()```, can I use this function to plot a trend line?

Comment: I just tried ```zyp.sen(temperature~date,tm14D)``` and the output is different from ```sens.slope()``` and ```mblm()```. The output generated is 0.0001272. What is the reason for different slope values? Is there something I am doing wrong?